# Cambio automático de tamaño de un JPanel dentro de otro JPanel

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo Múltiples JPanel y siempre que cambio de menú cambio a un JPanel nuevo, lo pinto dentro un JPanel que hay en el JFrame Principal, el problema es que cuando hago la ventana mas grande el JPanel(SubPanel) que hay dentro no cambia de tamaño y no se adapta al nuevo tamaño que tiene el JFrame.

```
public MainWindows() {
        initComponents();
        initSubPanel();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }


private void initSubPanel(){
    SubPanel subPanel = new SubPanel();
    subPanel.setSize(500, 500);
    subPanel.setLocation(0, 0);

    mainPanel.removeAll();
    mainPanel.add(subPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.revalidate();
    mainPanel.repaint();
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar el código que tienes la clase SubPanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Establece mainPanel con BorderLayout antes de añadir subPanel:

```
mainPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
```

Veo que estás añadiendo correctamente subPanel, así que esto hará que subPanel reajuste su tamaño al redimensionar mainPanel, no es necesario utilizar repaint y revalidate.

Saludos!

Comment: Era lo que estaba buscando, muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada, suerte en tus desarrollos. Saludos!